# How can I redisplay tcolorbox environments

Tags: tcolorbox

I created a new environment using `\newtcolorbox`, with auto numbering and a correctly-working TOC entry and everything.  The individual items appear exactly where they should within the chapters.  What I would like is to display all of these items again, at the end of a chapter or at the end of a part, or in an appendix or something.  I don't want another TOC; I want to display the actual environment items, the way they appear in the main body of the text, again in one big collection.  I haven't had any luck searching for an answer to this, so any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide a minimal working example that compiles and please have a look on the recording feature of `tcolorbox`, page 129 (section 8.3 of the current manual)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thank you, I think the recording feature is what I needed.  I will update when I figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

The `recording` feature of `tcolorbox` simplifies redisplaying of content. There are some approaches to use `recording`, I present only one here:

1. Define a `tcolorbox` environment, say `displaythis` which is meant for the first display of content and stores the content to a file named `\jobname.display\thetcbcounter`, which expands to `\jobname.display1`, `\jobname.display2` etc.
2. Say

   ```
   record={\string\redisplaythis[#1]{\jobname.display\thetcbcounter}}
   ```

   at the options list of the `displaythis` environment, which instructs `tcolorbox` to write `\redisplaythis{#1}{\jobname.display\thetcbcounter}` to the record file.
3. Define a total `tcolorbox` `reddisplaythis` which uses the mandatory argument in order to load the already stored content. (The `\NewTotalTColorBox` has the advantage, that the content of the box can be specified as well, contrary to `tcolorbox`)
4. Use `\tcbstartrecording[myenvironments.env]` before the first environment to be saved and `\tcbstoprecording` after the last one.
5. Apply `\tcbinputrecords[myenvironments.env]` for redisplay finally.

---

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter

\NewTColorBox[auto counter,list type=section,list inside=red]{displaythis}{O{}}{%
  enhanced, 
  sharp corners, 
  title={My nice Environment \thetcbcounter},
  saveto={\jobname.display\thetcbcounter},
  record={\string\redisplaythis[#1]{\jobname.display\thetcbcounter}},
  #1,
}

\NewTotalTColorBox[auto counter]{\redisplaythis}{O{}m}{
  enhanced, 
  sharp corners, 
  title={My nice Environment (again) \thetcbcounter},
  #1
}{\input{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tcbstartrecording[myenvironments.env]
\tcblistof{red}{List of environments}


\begin{displaythis}
\blindtext 
\end{displaythis}


\begin{displaythis}[colback=white!60!yellow]
\blindtext[2]
\end{displaythis}
\tcbstoprecording

\tcbinputrecords[myenvironments.env]

\end{document}
```

[image]